# Softether Access List not working

Tags: permissions, ip, vpn

I installed softether as VPN server on UBUNTU 12.4. nOW I add anonymous user for special range of ips. 
as you see blow i created a user named 'all' : 
[image]

and i created an access list to deny access from range of IPs:

[image]

Now access list not working and users can connect from all IPs.

Comment: I made a white list ip and set to iptables. so other IPs cant connect into it.

Comment: The images are really bad. could you describe in word what you did?